# Drop down initiated when click on enter on validated text box

Tags: c#, javascript, razor, drop-down-menu, asp.net-mvc-5

I've created a MVC5 App which was generated from my model by scaffold the view and controller,
In the model I have a drop down for dev and prod which is working fine, I have validation
for name for alpha-numeric and the problem is for e.g. user chooses prod (the second 
option)  and enters incorrect data in the name field and presses enter, the view is refreshed and 
the drop down changes the selection from prod to dev. How can I avoid that?

How can I ask in the view if the type is different than dev, if so put the selected item?

Model:

```
public class Ad
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Type
    {
        get
        {
            return new[]
            {
                new SelectListItem {Value = "D", Text = "Dev"},
                new SelectListItem {Value = "p", Text = "Prod"}
            };
        }
   }
```

View:

```
   <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SystemType, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
           @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Type, Model.Type)
        </div>
    </div>
```

**Edit the create operation**

```
@model WebApplication3.Models.Ad

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            debugger;

            $('select[name="Type"]').change(function () {
                if ($(this).val() === 'p') {
                    $('input[name="User"]').prop("disabled", true);
                    $('input[name="Password"]').prop("disabled", true);
                }
                else {
                    $('input[name="User"]').prop("disabled", false);
                    $('input[name="Password"]').prop("disabled", false);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Ad</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Type, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Type, Model.Type)
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.User, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.User)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.User)
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Password)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password)
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}

 public class AdController : Controller
 {
        private AdDBContext db = new AdDBContext();

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(db.Ad.ToList());
        }

        public ActionResult Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }

            Ad ad = db.Ad.Find(id);
            if (ad == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(ad);
        }

        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View( new Ad());
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include="ID,Name,User,Password")] Ad ad)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Ad.Add(ad);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(ad);
        }

        public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }

            Ad ad = db.Ad.Find(id);
            if (ad == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(ad);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include="ID,Name,User,Password")] Ad ad)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(ad).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(ad);
        }

        public ActionResult Delete(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Ad ad = db.Ad.Find(id);
            if (ad == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(ad);
        }

        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            Ad ad = db.Ad.Find(id);
            db.Ad.Remove(ad);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                db.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On dropdown change event write the selected option value in a hidden field and when page refreshed get the value from hidden field and set the selected item from the action.

```
$('select#Type').change(function(){

$('#selectedOne').val($(this).val());

});
```

and in you action read from FormCollection and set selected item of the SelectList

Create Hidden Field in view:

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SystemType, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
           @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Type, Model.Type)
          <input type="hidden" id="selectedOne" vlaue="" name="selectedOne" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

In your action:

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include="ID,Name,User,Password")] Ad ad,FormCollection form)
        {
            string selectedValue = form["selectedOne"].ToString();
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Ad.Add(ad);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            foreach(var item in ad.Type)
            {
              if(item.Value == selectedValue)
              {
                 item.Selected = true;
              }
            }

            return View(ad);
        }
```

**Solution 2:**

Another simple solution is to use `@Ajax.BeginForm` Hepler instead of `@Html.BeginForm`, so that form posted via ajax, and your dropdown will not get reset.

Comment: HI Ehsan - thank you very much for quick replay,Im new to this topic can you please add the code in the context of what I post.Thanks in advance,I voted up!

Comment: you are posting form to some action right, post that action code as well

Comment: post your get and post action as well

Comment: THank you very much ! Currently its not working ,when I debug it the  string selectedValue = form["selectedOne"]; return "" ,any idea? I not sure how it solve the problem since where do you pass the list box selected item value to the view?

Comment: have you wrote jquery event of dropdown

Comment: nop... I just using the  @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Type, Model.Type)...

Comment: @EhsanSajjad-I think you provided good solution but not to the end...:)

Comment: @JohnJerrby i was myself stuck somewhere let me complete it

Comment: well its complete i completed i forogt, what could more be in it , you can suggest

Comment: @shopiaT you need to write jquery dropdown selected item change event to keep track which was selected at last before form post

Comment: HI Ehsan,Sorry but Im not sure how to write it?Can you please provide example? btw since I put in the html (model => model.Type, Model.Type) the second parameter is always get the list ,do I need maybe to use additional property in the model to keep the selected item

Comment: this jquery chunk from the answer use this:
$('select#Type').change(function(){

$('#selectedOne').val($(this).val());

});

Comment: @EhsanSajjad- Thanks but I already use the script and its not working ,what about the bool how do you suggest to use ?

Comment: like this:return new[]
            {
                new SelectListItem {Value = "D", Text = "Dev",Selected=true},
                new SelectListItem {Value = "p", Text = "Prod"}
            };

Comment: @EhsanSajjad-Thanks for the effort...I was not able to solve this issue but I close this question and open new now with simple steps how to reproduce the issue,maybe you can help there :)

Comment: whats the link of that question?